What are the implications of Solana's stake-weighted mechanisms when choosing an RPC hosting solution?
I have read that many Solana mechanisms are stake-weighted and I was wondering what would be the implications of this when using services such as Helius or Quicknode vs a self-hosted (non staked) solution.
For instance, everything else being equal, would an RPC node hosted by Helius or Quicknode receive transactions with a lower average delay than a self-hosted RPC node as a result of those companies having their own staked validators?
Or similarly, everything else being equal, would an RPC node hosted by Helius/Quicknode be more likely to land transactions than a self-hosted one?

In scenarios where the network is uncongested, the advantage of using high-stake validators diminishes. This is because the network has sufficient capacity to process transactions quickly across the board, regardless of the stake weight behind them.

That makes sense - in moments of congestion then is it right to assume that there will be a better quality of service both for reduced latency and increased likelihood of transactions landing when using a staked service?

@Jesuspc During peak times or when the network faces congestion, Quality of Service (QoS) mechanisms that prioritize transactions from higher-staked nodes become highly significant. Transactions routed through RPC nodes associated with or operated by high-stake validators are more likely to be picked up and confirmed faster compared to those with less or no stake backing
